# Commerce problem on Checkout page - Getting Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have installed Sitecore.Demo.Retail and it is working fine overall.

Problem is on the checkout page where I am getting this error:

[image]

The underlying website error message is :

```
Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException
Message: An error occurred while processing this request.
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy
   at Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy.GetValue[T](DataServiceQuerySingle`1 query)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.IndexUtility.GetEnvironmentArtifactStoreId(String environmentName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Strategies.OrdersIntervalAsynchronousStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<IndexItems>b__0(String environment)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Strategies.OrdersIntervalAsynchronousStrategy.IndexItems()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Strategies.CommerceIntervalAsynchronousStrategy.Run()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.OperationMonitor.ExecuteActions(ConcurrentQueue`1 actions, String groupName)

Nested Exception

Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException
Message: InternalServerError
Source: Microsoft.OData.Client
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

The commerce engine logs are showing this error:

```
13 10:00:52 ERROR Connection id ""0HLAKHPSJ3QT8"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException: Resource not found for the segment 'GetEnvironmentArtifactStoreId'.
   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.CreateFirstSegment(String segmentText)
   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.ParsePath(ICollection`1 segments)
   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathFactory.BindPath(ICollection`1 segments, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUriParser.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.ODataRoute.<RouteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Has anyone experienced this before ?

Comment: is it a clean installation ?

Comment: Yes clean installation from master branch. I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: try to run Bootstrap() for CommerceAuthoring once again

Comment: I ran the bootstrap() got an ok message, also ran the initialze HabitatShops got an ok message but for HabitatAuthoring I get "Book name Habitat_PriceBook is already in use." Did the iisreset as well, still getting the same error.